# How to send base64 converted pdf using nodemailer

Tags: javascript, node.js, buffer, nodemailer

I have a base64 version of a pdf on my server which I can console.log and see the value of. The variable is called `encodedpdf` and doing `console.log(encodedpdf)` displays the base64 version of the pdf.

Nodemailer allows us to send a bsae64 file as an attachement and convert it using buffer. Below is the code

```
attachments: [{
            filename: 'main.pdf',
            content: new Buffer(encodedpdf,'base64')
          }]
```

However, I keep on getting this error

> TypeError: First argument must be a string, Buffer, ArrayBuffer,
>   Array, or array-like object

Edit1:

This is my front end code where I convert my pdf to base64 and send it as an ajax

```
 var element = document.getElementById('element-to-print');
           html2pdf().from(element).outputPdf().then(function(pdf) {
            const newpdf = btoa(pdf);    //This line
            $.post('./setup', newpdf, function(result) {
                console.log('result', result);
            });
```

I am getting a very large chunk of random strings at my backend post request therefore I am assuming that `btoa(pdf)` is converting my pdf to base64. Could there be a problem here?

Answer (score 1):

The ways you're using `new Buffer(String,'base64')` is [deprecated](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_new_buffer_string_encoding)

Please use the following way to encode string into base64

```
Buffer.from("I am a tring").toString('base64')
```

Or use nodemailer's built-in function to send your base64 encoded string pdf

```
filename: 'your.pdf',
content: 'encodedpdfstring', //EncodedString
encoding: 'base64'
```

Comment: I get this error

**TypeError: Invalid non-string/buffer chunk** using nodemailer

Comment: I made some changes to my question. Will you please look at it?